# Dúvida com checkbox e PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 2 campos, conforme abaixo, que são `checkboxes`:

```
              <tr>
              <td>Dizeres Legais:</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="export_dizeres[]" value="PORTUGUES"> Português
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_dizeres[]" value="INGLES"> Inglês
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_dizeres[]" value="ESPANHOL"> Espanhol
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_dizeres[]" value="FRANCES"> Francês
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_dizeres[]" value="ARABE"> Árabe
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_dizeres[]" value="COREANO"> Coreano</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td>Tabela Nutricional:</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[]" value="PORTUGUES"> Português
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[]" value="INGLES"> Inglês
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[]" value="ESPANHOL"> Espanhol
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[]" value="FRANCES"> Francês
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[]" value="ARABE"> Árabe
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[]" value="COREANO"> Coreano</td>
          </tr>
```

Passo eles para o PHP, consigo exibir eles da seguinte forma:

```
$listaDizeres = $_POST['export_dizeres'];

foreach ($listaDizeres as $export_dizeres) {
    echo $export_dizeres.'<br>';

}
$listaTabela = $_POST['export_tabela'];

foreach ($listaTabela as $export_tabela) {
    echo $export_tabela.'<br>';

}
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Preciso criar um campo para cada `checkbox` no banco ou posso gravar todo resultado junto em um único campo, como um array? No caso de posteriormente criar um formulário de alteração usando Ajax, consigo marcar corretamente os `checkboxes` buscando os dados no banco?

Comment: Por exemplo, N desses checkboxs aí estão associados com N usuários, então crie uma tabela associativa que terá o id do usuário e o id daquele checkbox. Não use campos que contenham varios valores isso ferre a primeira forma norma(1FN), uma coluna para cada checkbox já imaginou se o número aumentar muito? já tem ideia de como separar os valores para as colunas certas?

Comment: Pode usar o serialize($listaDizeres) e salvar no campo de dados, não? Isso não vai ser útil se exigir um SELECT futuro baseado nisso.

Comment: Na verdade cada check vai estar associado com um projeto, mas a relação vai ser sim N para N. Essa idéia de criar uma tabela a parte me pareceu a melhor solução. Vão ser sempre esses 12 campos (6 para cada). @lnkeliz, como funciona esse serialize?

Comment: A tabela a parte é melhor opção (ou uma coluna para cada item, o que também pode ser uma opção, mas não a melhor). O serialize irá exatamente tornar a array inteira em uma string, resumindo. Ele irá permitir enviar direto ao banco de dados toda a array "como está", poderá ler futuramente usando o unserialize($mysql['coluna']). O problema este método são vários, principalmente se pretende usar um "WHERE dizeres  = "Arabe" ou "JOIN..." será literalmente impossível, mas é justamente a opção de "posso gravar todo resultado junto em um único campo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Preciso criar um campo para cada checkbox no banco ou posso gravar
>   todo resultado junto em um único campo, como um array?

Eu não faria nenhum dos dois: eu criaria uma **tabela A** que contém 3 campos: id, chave e valor:

- O **id** é auto gerado;
- A **chave** é o que vai no seu **value=""** do input type;
- E o **valor** é o **texto do checkbox**.

Caso você queira simplificar, pode tirar a chave da tabela e constituir o atributo value="" do id da tabela.

Assim, para cadastrar o que o usuário selecionou, crie uma tabela que ligue usuario com a tabela A e jogue os ids lá =D

É o melhor método a ser usado por experiência própria na empresa em que trabalho, já tive esse problema.

> No caso de posteriormente criar um formulário de alteração usando Ajax, consigo marcar corretamente os checkboxes buscando os dados no banco?

Sim, sem problema desde que faça o select no banco correto.

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer desta forma! Muito obrigado.